# Google and Duplicate Content: Product details vs. separate feature explanation page

Tags: google, duplicate-content

I run the site `https://example.de` and I'm really really looking for an answer to the following question. We had three SEO agencies and each one gave a different answer.

The products need an explanation of the features, but where to put that explanation?

1. On a separate feature explanation page
2. On the product details page (like I've done here: `https://example.de/stammbuch-a5-paul`) with canonical tag of course.
3. On the category page (like I've done here: `https://example.de/hochzeitsgaestebuch/`)

Comment: I have removed the domain name from the question. If anyone needs to see your site, they can view the edits to see your original links. Cheers!!

Comment: What was the reasoning behind their suggestions? Can you share this?

Answer (score 1):

You first need to think about your **website architecture** and how it is relevant for users and searchers. In this [Webmasters Hangout](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fCMwhn8cZD4&feature=youtu.be&t=2361), John Mueller talked about the best site architecture.

> In general I’d be careful to avoid setting up a situation where normal website navigation doesn’t work. So we should be able to crawl from one URL to any other URL on your website just by following the links on the page

In addition to that, keep in mind that you should always provide content inside a good context.

> ... we don’t really know how these URLs are related to each other and it makes it really hard for us to be able to understand how relevant is this piece of content in the context of your website.

Having that in mind, let's check your options:

- **On a separate feature explanation page**: if it is a common page for multiple products and it have genuine and original content to rank for, it could be an option.
- **On the product details page**: if it's a second URL for the same product and you are using a canonical tag, it will never rank so it will not work for SEO. This could be an option without the canonical tag and integrated into the main product URL.
- **On the category page**: it could help to provide original content for this URL. Anyway, if we are adding multiple product details, it will be complicated to rank properly in searchers.

Comment: Congrats on making it to 3K! You can now [cast close and reopen votes](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions).